# Timed publishing in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I understand we can setup a time for our app update to go live using timed publishing.

I am also wanted to update the 'Store Listing' info at the same time (i.e. update the screenshots of the app, and update the description) will this information also be published at the same time of the app using timed publishing? Or does this update go live straight away. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that information won't be published until you press the Go Live button. Until that moment no changes will be released and store listing or screenshots changes will be saved as a draft.

Google play itself shows you an alert explaining it when you perform a change:

[image]

To ensure which changes are included in your Timed publishing release, you can check the changelog link beside the Go live button, and you will be able to see there those store listing, screenshot or whatsoever changes.